# Generate 100 data randomly, or select if it is possible

Tags: gams-math

I want to  test my model , I need to test it in some data , I want to generate data , in fact I want to have 125 different parameter from 0 to 10000.

For example , in below we have 4 different parameter ,from 1 to 300.

```
 Set I/0*300/;
 Parameter MyParameter;
 MyParameter /4 1,10 1,42 1,87 1/;
```

I don't want to do this by hand.

Is there any method that I generate it automaticly.

another way  asking:

how can Select 4 random element of a  set ' I' , without repetition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Set       I     /0*300/
          picks /p1*p4/;
Scalar    pick;
Parameter MyParameter(I);

MyParameter(I) = 0;
loop(picks,
  pick = uniformInt(1, card(I));

* Make sure to not pick the same one twice
  while(sum(I$(pick=ord(I)),MyParameter(I))=1,
    pick = uniformInt(1, card(I))
    Display 'here';
  );

  MyParameter(I)$(pick=ord(I))=1;
);
Display MyParameter;
```

Comment: thanks , it's work , can you more explain ,your code in 'while' , I can't understand what's happen in 'While' , and how it can  make sure to not pick element twice

Comment: The line "pick = uniformInt(1, card(I));" before the while could return a number, that was selected before already, since it is random. And since you want to see 4 different elements, I added the while... to make sure that you really get this. So, the $ condition checks, if the number chosen was chosen before already, and if this is the case, it selects a new one randomly until it picks one, that was not picked before. The display line can be ignored. It is unlikely, that this while is needed, because chances are high that you just get 4 different numbers out of 300, but I wanted to be sure.