# using uniform distribution to generate random data

Tags: gams-math

is it possible to have a parameter like randP(j) such that ,5 element of randP select randomly then these elements fill with random-int , and other elements have value 0.

```
    set j/1*50/;
    parameter randP(j); 
*select 5 elements (5 location j) randomly 
*fill 5 locations by random integer value 
*fill other locations  by 0
```

Comment: Have a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52028444/generate-100-data-randomly-or-select-if-it-is-possible 
I think if you replace `MyParameter(I)$(pick=ord(I))=1;` by `MyParameter(I)$(pick=ord(I))=uniformInt(1, 100);` (or similiar), you should, what you need.